# Prevent last element in char * vector from changing

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am reading strings in C++ using `fread` where I am reading and storing `shortSiteText` in siteNames_. siteNames_ is declared as `std::vector<char*> siteNames_;`  I use siteNames_ in other functions but because `shortSiteText` is a pointer, when I call the delete command on it, the last entry in `siteNames_` is changed. How do I prevent this?

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= nSites; i ++){
   fread((char *) &shortSiteTextLength, 1, sizeof shortSiteTextLength, baseFile_);
   shortSiteText = new char[shortSiteTextLength];
   fread(shortSiteText,1, shortSiteTextLength,baseFile_);
   siteNames_.push_back(shortSiteText);
}
delete [] shortSiteText;
```

I tried to use the dereference operator: `siteNames_.push_back(*shortSiteText);` but that generates a compiler error.

**NOTE: I must use fread and char* due to legacy code.**

Comment: Why not use `std::string`? Anytime you have `delete` in your code, something could very likely be improved.

Comment: @GMan, I am using legacy code elsewhere

Comment: That's what `c_str`/`data`/`&s[0]` is for. And if that won't work for you, do `std::vector<char>` and `&v[0]` instead. **You should never have to manually delete something.** Your entire problem is because of unclear ownership, because you're trying to take it into your own hands. It's unsafe and bug-ridden.

Comment: Just what are the exact needs of the legacy code? Does it specifically need `std::vector<char*>`? Or does just need to be given each entry as a `char*` regardless of how they are contained elsewhere? If you explain some of the details, we might be able to offer a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's zoom on this:

```
shortSiteText = new char[shortSiteTextLength];
siteNames_.push_back(shortSiteText);
delete [] shortSiteText;
```

**Explanation**: The second line just pushes a pointer to the array, not the array itself. The first line then desallocate the array, on which the last element of siteNames still points to; this leads to undefined behavior when you use this element.

**Hack**: Remove `delete [] shortSiteText`

**Real fix**: You encounter this problem because you try to manage object ownerships yourself. Don't ! Here, you can use `std::string` and still be able to work with legacy code, with the `c_str()` member function.

To quote a friend of mine:

> As a general rule, if you are a
>   beginner and your code contains the
>   word 'char', you have a bug.

Comment: I agree with that quote, I was more or less forced into using char and was not happy about it. I was hoping to avoid hacking the solution without serious code overhaul, appears I can't do that

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: Did you even read my comment? You *don't* need manual allocation of char's.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot `delete[]` anything you push into the `vector` until the associated `vector` element is done with.

It's not clear to me what the intent of this code is - you are only deleting the last-used value of `shortSitetext` anyhow, so this does not do what you think (which is trying to avoid leaking memory by matching `new` with `delete`, I think).

Remove the last line of code, and manually clean up the `vector` when you are done with it by iterating over the elements calling `delete[]` for each, then `clear()` the `vector`.

Or use `boost::ptr_vector`, which will do this automagically for you.

Or use `vector<string>`, to decouple the legacy `char*` code from your modern, non raw pointer using C++ world. You can push_back `const char*` directly to a `vector<string>` like so:

```
const char* str;
// init str to the value you wish

vector<string> vec;
vec.push_back(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete shortSiteText until you want to remove the data from the vector.

You've created a chunk of memory, set the data, and saved the pointer in your vector. The memory you delete is the same memory that the vector element points to.

Just removed the `delete [] shortSiteText;` line.

But, be sure that when you're done with the vector, to carefully remove and delete each pointer.